# Passing an array

Tags: c#, generics

In the sample code below, why does the call to ArrayMethod fail for a genric type when I don't include the `class` constraint

```
public interface IFoo { }
public interface IBar : IFoo { }

public class Test
{
    public void ClassConstraintTest<T>() where T : class, IFoo
    {
        T[] variable = new T[0];
        ArrayMethod(variable);
    }

    public void GenericTest<T>() where T : IFoo
    {
        T[] variable = new T[0];
        ArrayMethod(variable);  // Compilation error:  Can't convert T[] to IFoo[]
    }

    public void InheritanceTest()
    {
        IBar[] variable = new IBar[0];
        ArrayMethod(variable);
    }

    public void ArrayMethod(IFoo[] args) { }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

It's because [array covariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664572(v=vs.71).aspx), i.e., the fact that `MySubtype[]` is a subtype of `MyType[]`, only works for reference types. The `class` constraint ensures that `T` is a reference type.

(Note that, in retrospect, array covariance is [considered to be a bad idea](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance/). Try to avoid it if you can, for example, by making `ArrayMethod` generic or by using `IEnumerable<IFoo>` instead.)

Comment: A good type system should have a covariant type which can be used as an array whose items can be read, swapped, or copied within the array.  Array types in .NET and Java may safely be used in covariant fashion as such types, and may be safely used in non-covariant fashion as freely-writable collections.  Perhaps it would have been better to have multiple kinds of references to arrays, with different advertised abilities, but IMHO those who simply say covariant arrays were a "mistake" haven't really figured out the costs of the alternatives.

Answer (score 5):

In short: array covariance only works when both arrays are of a reference (`class`) type.

To understand this, you have to understand the memory layout of different types of arrays. In C# we have value arrays (`int[]`, `float[]`, `DateTime[]`, any user-defined `struct[]`) where each thing is stored sequentially inside the array, and reference arrays (`object[]`, `string[]`, any user-defined `class[]`, `interface[]`, or `delegate[]`) where references are stored sequentially inside the array and the objects are stored outside the array wherever they fit in memory.

When you request that the method work on any `T` (without the `: class` constraint) you allow for either of those two types of arrays, but the compiler knows for a fact that any `int[]` (or any other value array) is not going to somehow magically become a valid `IFoo[]` (or any other reference array) and forbids the conversion. This happens even if your struct implements `IFoo` for no other reason than `IFoo[]` is a reference array and a `T[]` will be a value array.

However, when you specify that `T` is a reference type (i.e. the `class` declaration), it is now possible that the `T[]` is a valid `IFoo[]` because they are both reference arrays. So the compiler allows the code using the array covariance rules (which state you can use `T[]` where `IFoo[]` is required because `T` is a subtype of `IFoo`).